# Homomorphism and modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Going through old notes I see following problem.

$X$ and $Y$ are modules over $\mathbb{Z}$

i) $ \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(X,\mathbb{Z})\cong _{\mathbb{Z}} \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(Y,\mathbb{Z})$ follows $X \cong _{\mathbb{Z}}Y$

ii) $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z},X)\cong _{\mathbb{Z}} \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z},Y)$ follows $X \cong _{\mathbb{Z}}Y$

It says i) is always true while  ii) isn't necessarily true.
However I don't see this conclusion at all? Anyone has a idea why its like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the contrary: i) is false and ii) is true.

*A counter-example to i)*: 
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Z}}(\mathbf{Z}/m\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z})=\{0\}=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Z}}(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z}),$$
however $\;\mathbf{Z}/m\mathbf{Z}\simeq \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ only if $m=n$.

*ii)* is trivial, as for any ring $R$ and any $R$-module $M$, one has a canonical isomorphism:
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(R,M)\simeq M,$$
which maps a linear map $u$ (from $R$ to $M$) to $u(1)\in M$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Invested 1,5 hours finding the solution when the notes are wrong.

Comment: It happens from time to time to all of us. I remember, when I was a student, not understanding a point of a (rather long) proof in David Mumford's *RedBook*, having a counter-example to an assertion in the proof, asking everyone what I did not understand, until I understood there was a typo – a comma placed *after* a word in a sentence, instead of before the word, and this changed the meaning. I had lost one month…